# Convert a dict of bytes to json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm trying to convert:

```
response data = {'policy': b'eyJleHBpcmF0a', 'signature': b'TdXjfAp'}
```

to json:

```
jsonified = json.dumps( response_data )
```

but it results in error message:

> TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable

What is the proper way to make the proper conversion ?

Expected result

```
jsonified = {"policy": "eyJleHBpcmF0a", "signature": "TdXjfAp"}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could write your own encoder for types that can not be serialized out-of-the-box:

```
import json

class MyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, (bytes, bytearray)):
            return obj.decode("ASCII") # <- or any other encoding of your choice
        # Let the base class default method raise the TypeError
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

data = {'policy': b'eyJleHBpcmF0a', 'signature': b'TdXjfAp'}
jsonified = json.dumps( data, cls=MyEncoder )
print(jsonified)
# {"policy": "eyJleHBpcmF0a", "signature": "TdXjfAp"}
```

This approach can easily be extended to support other types, such das datetime.

Just make sure you end up with a str/int/float/... or any other serializeable type at the end of the function.

As @Tomalak pointed out, you could also use a base64 encoding instead of the ASCII encoding to make sure you support control characters.

Comment: `obj.decode("ASCII")` is not optimal. Use base64 for bytes.

Comment: @Tomalak agreed, but then it would not match OP's expected output.

Comment: Yeah, that's because the OP's expected output is wrong. I bet he did not think about the possibility of control characters showing up in the byte sequence. :) If `'signature'` means what I think it means, there is no way around base64.